# unable to add text to textarea

Tags: java, javafx

I m looking forward to update a textarea based on some specific value.In order to make this task simpler I made this sample program that sets simple `client`   text in the text area but it is not visible in text area. Here is my code

```
public class myController extends Stage implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
         snames=new TextArea(); 
    }   
    public void serverStart(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/serverSecond.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());
        this.setScene(scene);
        this.show();
        snames.setText("clients");
    }
    @FXML TextArea snames;
}
```

I also tried removing this line `snames=new TextArea();` but then it shows `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION` .Thanks for help

Comment: If `myController ` is the controller of the FXML file `serverSecond.fxml` you should not load the FXML file in it. The `FXMLLoader` will create a controller instance and will inject the fields into. Load the FXML file where you need this controller (e.g. in the `Application`) and then the `TextArea` will be injected properly.

Comment: post your error code.

Comment: Why does your controller extend Stage? Why are you opening a new view within your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line of code:

> snames=new TextArea();

If you are doing this:

> @FXML TextArea snames;

There there is no need to do this:

> snames=new TextArea();